# Android AVD taking a long time to load

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Does anyone know how long it should take to load an AVD in Android Studio? This is on the latest version of Android Studio. I just setup the environment on my MBP to test out an API and run the Camera2 code sample from Google.

Launching emulator takes a long time:
[image]

Comment: Perform `adb devices logcat` and see logs from emulator, hopefully you'll notice something abnormal.

Comment: all I see is:CATOMACPPTN:platform-tools pptn$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554 offline